# Recursion does not stop

Tags: c++, recursion, depth-first-search, directed-acyclic-graphs

I am writing code for finding cycle in a graph using a DFS algorithm . However , when I go to print the path of the cycle , something very odd happens . Read my concern in the comments.

```
#include <iostream> 
#include "graph.h" 
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int discovered[MAXV+1];
int parent[MAXV+1];

//Printing path that contains the cycle 

void find_path(int start, int end)
{
    int s = start;
    int e = end;

    while(s != e)
    {
        cout<<s<<" ";
        s = parent[s];
    }

/*The loop above does not stops ; 
  which means the condition parent[s] == e ;
  does not meet . However , on printing out the 
  values of s , parent[s] , and e , on successive iteration 
  I can see that the value of parent[s] and e becomes
  equal after a certain time , even though the loop does not 
  terminate.

*/
}

void dfs(graph *g , int start)
{    
    int dis = 1;
    int u = 0 ;
    edgenode *p;

    p = g->edges[start]; 
    discovered[start] = dis;

    while(p!= NULL)
    {
        u = p->y;
        parent[u] = start;

        if(discovered[u]== 1){ cout<<"Cycle"<<start<<u<<endl; find_path(start,u);}
        else dfs(g,u);

        p = p->next;
    }

    discovered[start] = dis +1;
    printf("\n");   
}

int main()
{
    for(int i= 1; i<=MAXV+1; i++)
    {
        discovered[i] = false;
        parent[i] = -1;
    }

    graph *g = new graph();
    read_graph(g,true);

    dfs(g,1);
}
```

So , is there flaw in my logic in calling the above recursion , or my g++ compiler is acting weird . Any perusal of my code will be highly appreciated . Thanks .

P.S:You can assume that I have a graph structure already implemented , which I incorporate during compile time . And I assume that you have a good idea about the implementation of BFS algorithm . If you have any concern of understanding the code , let me know .

Comment: You pass `start` as `1` to `dfs` and use it as an array index (as far as I can tell). Why do you skip the `0` (which is the start index of normal arrays)?

Comment: And the discovered[] and parent[] arrays are initialized at index 1 as well...maybe a red herring, but it kinda sticks out there...

Comment: Don't concentrate on that parent , I have a separate graph structure ; and I know that should run dfs on every single node . Please concentrate on find_part(start,u) part of the dfs section which takes in two nodes as argument ,the parent node and another node which the recursion in dfs has already visited . The implementation of find_path is where the problem is .

Comment: At the very least, you are writing past the bounds of the `discovered` and `parent` arrays. Index `MAXV+1` is not valid for these arrays. Valid indexes range from `0` to `MAXV` (inclusive).

Comment: Without the `graph.h` header, this code does not compile. Please **provide a minimal compiling example that displays the problem**.

Comment: so it seems your actual problem is not with the dfs algorithm *per se*, but with the loop in `find_path` function - can you give us example numbers in `parent` array and according `start`/`end` parameters, where the loop fails to stop?

Comment: For those interested in my code ; there are 3 file , one is dfs.cpp ,another grap.cpp and another graph.h , that I embedded in pastebin.http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=qAmwCgQJ http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=RQaE97u0 http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=PB0cCwNy

Comment: @nyarlathotep : 1->2 ; 1->6 ; 2->3 ; 3->4 ; 4->5 ; 5->1 ; 5->2 : example of node a and node b, having 6 verices and 7 edges . If you have a compiler around please run the code I pasted in pastebin , and give input like this : 6 7 ; 1 2 ; 1 6 ; 2 3 ; 3 4 ; 4 5 ; 5 1; 5 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The algorithm in `dfs` is broken. As it examines the edges from node 1, it finds an edge from node 1 to node 2, and it marks 1 as a parent of 2. Later, it finds an edge from node 5 to node 2, and it marks 5 as a parent of 2, replacing the previous entry in the `parent` array.

Later yet, when it determines there is a cycle from 1 to 5 (to 1), it calls `find_path(5, 1)`. However, `find_path` can never find node 1, because following the parents from 5 leads to 4, 3, 2, and back to 5.

Comment: Yes , thanks , my logic of visiting a node in dfs was faulty , I visited the same node twice and changed its parents twice .